# Не могу купить $arbuz

Tags: криптовалюта

Не могу купить $arbuz. При попытке купить на dedust идет бесконечная загрузка, или же вообще не дает нажать на кнопку купить
Что делать не пойму, пробовал впн не помогло

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Этот вопрос задан не по теме сообщества StackOverflow. Вы можете подробнее ознакомится с темами на которые можно задавать вопросы [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте отключится от вайфай и купить арбуз по обычной мобильной сети, либо поставьте меньше - учитывая комиссию перевода TON/Arbuz